# Fade In Fade Out Android Animation in Java

Tags: android, animation

I want to have a 2 second animation of an ImageView that spends 1000ms fading in and then 1000ms fading out.

Here's what I have so far in my ImageView constructor:

```
Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
fadeIn.setDuration(1000);

Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
fadeOut.setStartOffset(1000);
fadeOut.setDuration(1000);

AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(true);
animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
this.setAnimation(animation);
```

When I run that animation, *nothing* shows up. However, when I remove one of the alpha animations, the behavior works as expected.

Things I have already tried:

- Every conceivable combination of `setFillBefore`, `setFillAfter`, and `setFillEnabled`.
- Adding a `LinearInterpolator` to the `AnimationSet`.

Comment: Yes you can fade images in and out! This tutorial should do the trick. http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.com/2011/04/performing-animation-in-android.html

Comment: That tutorial describes a method using XML. Do you know how to achieve the same thing using Java?

Comment: Well, Im not next to my programming computer so I cant test this code, but you can set xml attributes in java. this is the original code:    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
android:duration="300" />    \n so you can probably MyTween.setDurationg(300) MyTween.fromAlpha(0.0) MyTween(1.0)

Answer (score 291, accepted):

Figured out my own problem. The solution ended up being based in interpolators.

```
Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); //add this
fadeIn.setDuration(1000);

Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); //and this
fadeOut.setStartOffset(1000);
fadeOut.setDuration(1000);

AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false); //change to false
animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
this.setAnimation(animation);
```

#### If you are using Kotlin

```
val fadeIn = AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f)
fadeIn.interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator() //add this
fadeIn.duration = 1000

val fadeOut = AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f)
fadeOut.interpolator = AccelerateInterpolator() //and this
fadeOut.startOffset = 1000
fadeOut.duration = 1000

val animation = AnimationSet(false) //change to false
animation.addAnimation(fadeIn)
animation.addAnimation(fadeOut)
this.setAnimation(animation)
```

Comment: What if you want to do 5 or 6 fading in/out, with really small delays like 100 for each, could you use something like this ? I tried but it's not really fluid. The aim was to simulate for example a bulb that would not work properly, and twinkle.

Comment: try and call this.setAnimation in a loop

Comment: I was thinking I fade out last bg img and fad in the current one, but this answer inspires me that I only need to fade in the current bg img and fade out the current one, cause AlphaAnimation can't fadein/out two different imgs.

Comment: I don't think you need to have two independent animations... I think you could have a single animation and set the parameter: fadeInOut.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

Comment: Second: if you wanted to repeat, no need to call in a loop like @jonney said. use fadeInOut.setRepeatCount(6) - change 6 to be how many you wish it to repeat. Much less overhead to let the native C++ code in Android do all this instead of calling in a Java loop.

Comment: This was really useful, In case you like this same effect but purely on xml check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50035858/3908170)

Comment: On the second line, I believe there should be `AccelerateInterpolator` used as well, since you are going from alpha 0 to 1.

Answer (score 166):

I know that this already has been answered but.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0" 
    android:toAlpha="0.0" 
    android:duration="1000"    
    android:repeatCount="infinite" 
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    />
```

Quick and easy way to quickly do a fade in and out with a self repeat. Enjoy

**EDIT** :
In your activity add this:

```
yourView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(co‌​ntext, R.anim.yourAnimation));
```

Comment: +1 Because with this answer I could make a secuence of fade in, fade out and fade in (just setting repeatCount="2"). I couldn't concatenating animations as the accepted answer proposes.

Comment: After declaring this `alpha` resource how can I use it?. Thanks

Comment: zozelfelfo it is just a animation xml so load it into code and then call startAnimation on whatever view you want it to affect.

Comment: @KonradWinkowski startAnimation method requires Animation object as argument! what should i pass to it?

Comment: For those looking for a more complete answer: `viewToAnimate.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in_out)`, where there is a fade_in_out.xml file in the anim folder under res.

Answer (score 39):

```
viewToAnimate.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(1000).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        viewToAnimate.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(1000).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Elegante for Marshmallow!

Comment: An important point to note is that you need to reset the `setStartDelay()` to 0 in the first animation if you are using it in the second animation to delay its start. Else it remembers that delay for any subsequent animation.

Answer (score 28):

Here is my solution using AnimatorSet which seems to be a bit more reliable than AnimationSet.

```
// Custom animation on image
ImageView myView = (ImageView)splashDialog.findViewById(R.id.splashscreenImage);

ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "alpha",  1f, .3f);
fadeOut.setDuration(2000);
ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "alpha", .3f, 1f);
fadeIn.setDuration(2000);

final AnimatorSet mAnimationSet = new AnimatorSet();

mAnimationSet.play(fadeIn).after(fadeOut);

mAnimationSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
        mAnimationSet.start();
    }
});
mAnimationSet.start();
```

Comment: I had to use an ObjectAnimator instead of an Animation to get a working solution because for some reason, whenever I started an AlphaAnimation, it ran twice and did some weird flickering.

Comment: elegant solution

Comment: Well, its too late but I think this might be help some, kindly clear animation before use it again on same view..

Answer (score 24):

**Another alternative:**

No need to define 2 animation for **fadeIn** and **fadeOut**. **fadeOut** is reverse of **fadeIn**.

So you can do this with **Animation.REVERSE** like this:

```
AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
alphaAnimation.setDuration(1000);
alphaAnimation.setRepeatCount(1);
alphaAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
view.findViewById(R.id.imageview_logo).startAnimation(alphaAnimation);
```

then **onAnimationEnd**:

```
alphaAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            //TODO: Run when animation start
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            //TODO: Run when animation end
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            //TODO: Run when animation repeat
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 17):

As I believe in the power of XML (for layouts), this is the equivalent for the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6822116/3908170), but purely as an animation resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"
        android:duration="1000" />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:startOffset="1000"/>
</set>
```

The `fillAfter` is for the fade to remain after completing the animation. The `interpolator` handles [interpolation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator) of the animations, as you can guess. You can also use other types of interpolators, like Linear or Overshoot.

Be sure to start your animation on your view:

```
yourView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(co‌​ntext, R.anim.fade));
```

Comment: @KGCybeX no problem, glad I could help :)

Comment: Very helpful and clean. Works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 11):

Here is what I used to fade in/out Views, hope this helps someone.

```
private void crossFadeAnimation(final View fadeInTarget, final View fadeOutTarget, long duration){
    AnimatorSet mAnimationSet = new AnimatorSet();
    ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fadeOutTarget, View.ALPHA,  1f, 0f);
    fadeOut.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            fadeOutTarget.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        }
    });
    fadeOut.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

    ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fadeInTarget, View.ALPHA, 0f, 1f);
    fadeIn.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            fadeInTarget.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
    });
    fadeIn.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    mAnimationSet.setDuration(duration);
    mAnimationSet.playTogether(fadeOut, fadeIn);
    mAnimationSet.start();
}
```

Comment: Somehow this is the only answer that includes setting visibility, nice

Answer (score 11):

If you use Animator for make animation you can

**anim** (directory) -> **fade_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

In java

```
Animator animator = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.animator.fade_out);
animator.setTarget(the_view_you_want_to_animation);
animator.setDuration(1000);
animator.start();
```

Other way to make animation fade out with only java code is

```
ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(the_view_you_want_to_animation, "alpha",  1f, 0);
fadeOut.setDuration(2000);
fadeOut.start();
```

Comment: in directory anim* not animator

Comment: @LeTadas in directory animator, according to Android Studio

Comment: `android:duration="1000"`

Answer (score 10):

AnimationSets don't appear to work as expected at all. In the end I gave up and used the Handler class's postDelayed() to sequence animations.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use animationListener, something like this:

```
fadeIn.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        this.startAnimation(fadeout);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I really like [Vitaly Zinchenkos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5247331/vitaly-zinchenko) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32999420/1247248) since it was short.

Here is an even briefer version in kotlin for a simple fade out

```
viewToAnimate?.alpha = 1f
viewToAnimate?.animate()
             ?.alpha(0f)
             ?.setDuration(1000)
             ?.setInterpolator(DecelerateInterpolator())
             ?.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is another alternative in Kotlin**

Done progamatically using ObjectAnimator

- Uses only one animation
- Does not muck with the animation listeners

  ```
  private fun getFadeAnimation(v: View?): ObjectAnimator 
    return ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "alpha", .3f, 1f).apply {
        repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
        repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.REVERSE
        duration = 1000
    }
  }
  ```

Create only one instance in the activity and then use:

```
val animator = getFadeAnimator(myView)
animator.start()
animator.end()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an "anim" directory in it:

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
android:duration="1000" >
```

Create an "anim" directory in it:

```
val fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in)
    imageView.startAnimation(fadeIn)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).