# Animation fade in and out

Tags: android, android-animation

Using this code I only have a fade in, I'm looking for how to add a fade out as well. I've added another xml called "fadeout" but I can't integrate it in my code.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
imageView.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        imageView.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
    }
}
```

fadein.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" 
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
   android:duration="Your Duration(in milisecond)"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
 </set>
```

Answer (score 39):

Here is my solution.  It uses AnimatorSet.  AnimationSet library was too buggy to get working.  This provides seamless and infinite transitions between fade in and out.

```
public static void setAlphaAnimation(View v) {
    ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "alpha",  1f, .3f);
    fadeOut.setDuration(2000);
    ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "alpha", .3f, 1f);
    fadeIn.setDuration(2000);

    final AnimatorSet mAnimationSet = new AnimatorSet();

    mAnimationSet.play(fadeIn).after(fadeOut);

    mAnimationSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            mAnimationSet.start();
        }
    });
    mAnimationSet.start();
}
```

Comment: How to stop this animation?

Answer (score 20):

This is Good Example for **`Fade In and Fade Out Animation with Alpha Effect`**

[Animate Fade In Fade Out](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/02/animate-fade-infade-out-by-changing.html)

**UPDATED :**

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6822116/1160282) may this help you

Comment: it's not exact: after fade out image show without fade effect, same for fade in.

Answer (score 18):

I´ve been working in Kotlin (recommend to everyone), so the syntax might be a bit off.
What I do is to simply to call:

```
v.animate().alpha(0f).duration = 200
```

I think that, in Java, it would be the following.:

```
v.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(200);
```

Try:

```
private void hide(View v, int duration) {
    v.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(duration);
}

private void show(View v, int duration) {
    v.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(duration);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add " ; " at last, Like = v.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(200);

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation  [AnimationSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html)

> Represents a group of Animations that should be played together. The
>   transformation of each individual animation are composed together into
>   a single transform. If AnimationSet sets any properties that its
>   children also set (for example, duration or fillBefore), the values of
>   AnimationSet override the child values

```
AnimationSet mAnimationSet = new AnimationSet(false); //false means don't share interpolators
```

> Pass true if all of the animations in this set should use the
>   interpolator associated with this AnimationSet. Pass false if each
>   animation should use its own interpolator.

```
ImageView imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
Animation fadeOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);
mAnimationSet.addAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
mAnimationSet.addAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
imageView.startAnimation(mAnimationSet);
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

we can simply use:

```
public void animStart(View view) {
    if(count==0){
        Log.d("count", String.valueOf(count));
        i1.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
        i2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
        count =1;
    }
    else if(count==1){
        Log.d("count", String.valueOf(count));
        count =0;
        i2.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
        i1.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
    }
}
```

where i1 and i2 are defined in the onCreateView() as:

```
    i1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.firstImage);
    i2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.secondImage);
```

count is a class variable initilaized to 0.

The XML file is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/secondImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="animStart"
            android:src="@drawable/second" />
      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/firstImage"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"

          android:onClick="animStart"
          android:src="@drawable/first" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

*@drawable/first* and *@drawable/second* are the images in the drawable folder in res.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this also in kotlin like this:

```
    contentView.apply {
        // Set the content view to 0% opacity but visible, so that it is visible
        // (but fully transparent) during the animation.
        alpha = 0f
        visibility = View.VISIBLE

        // Animate the content view to 100% opacity, and clear any animation
        // listener set on the view.
        animate()
                .alpha(1f)
                .setDuration(resources.getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime).toLong())
                .setListener(null)
    }
```

[read more about this in android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reveal-or-hide-view)

Answer (score 1):

Today, I got stuck with this problem. This worked for me:

```kotlin
    @JvmStatic
    fun setFadeInFadeOutAnimation(v: View?) {
        val fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "alpha", 0.0f, 1f)
        fadeIn.duration = 300
        val fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "alpha", 1f, 0.0f)
        fadeOut.duration = 2000

        fadeIn.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter(){
            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                fadeOut.start()
            }
        })
        fadeIn.start()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code for repeated fade-out/fade-in animation

```
AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.3f);
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    anim.setDuration(300);
view.setAnimation(anim); // to start animation
view.setAnimation(null); // to stop animation
```

Answer (score 0):

FOR FADE add this first line with your animation's object.

```
.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
```

FOR EXAMPLE[image: I USED LottieAnimation]