# Make a simple fade in animation in Swift for apple watch?

Tags: swift, animation, view, apple-watch

How can i make simple animations for apple watch in swift?

i have checked this [blog](http://natashatherobot.com/watchkit-animate/)

but its about frame animation, i am asking for fade in , fade out , rotate vs animations

such as using this low level function

```
 self.view.setAlpha(0.0)
```

I have android background , so i am searching for some swift functions for apple watch like in android equvalent of

```
Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
imageView.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation );
```

check [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156837/animation-fade-in-and-out)

or [or this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25535955/1880500) for

```
ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "alpha", .3f, 1f);
fadeIn.setDuration(2000)
```

Answer (score 4):

In apple watch code you just type

```
animateWithDuration(0.3) {
    self.view.setAlpha(0.0)
}
```

the method animateWithDuration is part of WKInterfaceController