# Android: button fade out issue

Tags: java, android, animation, button, fade

I have created a button that fades in when it is being touched and fades out when it isn't. I was able to achieve this by using setAlpha in java. The code and the problem is shown below:

```
    buttonPressed.getBackground().setAlpha(0);

    buttonPressed.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                buttonPressed.getBackground().setAlpha(255);
                buttonPressed.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
                return true;
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                buttonPressed.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The issue I have is whenever I release the button, the alpha is set to 0 before `animationFadeOut` is able to fully play, so the button does not fade back.

If I remove the line:

```
buttonPressed.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
```

then `animationFadeOut` will play but it will immediately go back to `setAlpha(255)`.

How can I get `animationFadeOut` to play fully and have the button alpha be `0` when the user stops touching the button?

Answer (score 1):

I think using setInterpolator() for fadeIn and fadeOut animation solves your problem.
eg: 
    Animation animationFadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    animationFadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animationFadeIn.setDuration(1000);

```
Animation animationFadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
animationFadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
animationFadeOut.setDuration(1000);
```

I got his solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796139/fade-in-fade-out-android-animation-in-java) link and you can know more about AccelerateInterpolator [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AccelerateInterpolator.html).

Currently unable to test it. But seems to be promising. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Better not to set the alpha manually, use animators to set the alpha

```
// Define the animators
Animation fadeInAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
Animation fadeOutAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);

// Duration of animation
fadeInAnimation.setDuration(1000);
fadeOutAnimation.setDuration(1000);

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        buttonPressed.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
        return true;
     } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        buttonPressed.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
        return true;
     }
     return false;
  }
```

Comment: With this code, the button would be at full alpha before the animation, and full alpha after the fade out animation is played. I was wondering how I can start and end with 0 alpha, but play the animations when the button is touched. I forgot to mention in my code but I actually have another line to set the button to 0 alpha (updated in the edit). How can I  get the button back to 0 alpha when the touch is released. Thanks!