# How to make the text fade for seconds

Tags: java, android

How to make the text fade for only 20 seconds and then disappear when you click the button

This is the code

```
 public void scoreOpenB(View v) {

        findViewById(R.id.main_mess).setVisibility(View.GONE);

     ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.main_mess)).setText(R.string.btn_closs);
        findViewById(R.id.main_mess).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE );
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear from your post what the issue  you are having is or perhaps if this is a solution? Please can you you review this?

Comment: Maybe it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796139/fade-in-fade-out-android-animation-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AsyncTask to update UI after delay. Try this ;)

```
    public void scoreOpenB(View v) {

        View updateMe = findViewById(R.id.main_mess);
        updateMe.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        new UpdateUI().execute(updateMe);
    }
}


private class updateUI extends AsyncTask<View, Integer, Long> {
    View toUpdate;

    protected void doInBackground(View view) {
        toUpdate = view;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        (toUpdate(TextView)).setText(R.string.btn_closs);
        toUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
}
```