# Why is there no files inside my anim folder?

Tags: android, animation

[The android view in the left side of Android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4idf7.png)

I was trying to add this code but the 'fade_in' in the code: "R.anim.fade_in;" is red. Then I check my res folder but there was no anim folder. Do I have to create this code? If I have to, can you please link/give me the codes for it? Thank you. Oh and is 'fade_in.xml' file supposed to be there on default or no?

The API I'm using is API 19 Kitkat 4.4 (I think).

The files inside that anim folder, I got it from the internet.

I am using Android Studio 2.3.3

Comment: You have to create anim folder inside res file. And Inside your anim folder you can write code

Comment: So it is not there by default? the fade_in and fade_out codes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796139/fade-in-fade-out-android-animation-in-java/6822116#6822116   Checkout this Post