# RecyclerView- set transparency of it and items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, transparency

I have a recyclerview with some TextView items displaying on top of my camera and I also have SeekBar which I want to use to set transparency of my list and components on it. So what I want to do is when I change the seekbar the transparency changes. My seekbar is working fine and I want to have it from 0% to 100%.

Comment: Take a look at the `setAlpha()` proptery. You can set the level of transparency with a float value from 0-1.  Whereby the value 0 is 100% transparent and 1 is 100% opaque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to manually adjust the alpha of each view.  So you would listen for changes to the seek bar, and when that happens, you will need to use animation to fade your elements in or out (using alpha - which can be thought of as transparency).

[Fade In Fade Out Android Animation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796139/fade-in-fade-out-android-animation-in-java)

Comment: I have not used the animation but changing alpha on each TextView (Background and TextColor(argb) worked. )